# how to load images stored outside 'public' folder laravel 4

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to save the images outside 'public' folder in laravel 4? I've tried to change the dir path, not on the public folder, the photos are saving to the dir path I've created, but it's not showing on my view. Hope somebody will help. How to view the images outside the public folder?

This is the working code inside the public folder.

```
<img src="{{app('customURL')}}userImage/{{$userDP}}" 
class="img-rounded  img-responsive center-block 
profilethumb profilethumbborder " />
```

This is my code outside the public folder.

```
<img src="{{app('customURL')}}C:\Users\cm-cmp102
\Desktop\Images/{{$userDP}}" class="img-rounded 
img-responsive  center-block profilethumb profilethumbborder " />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that but in this case you must programmatically serve the images as there is no direct access where Apache can server it for you.

In this case you need to create another controller, make it listen to images path, read the file when needed and then manually sending file content as a response.